# Docker-compose on VSTS

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a .net core app that i want to run on docker.
I used VS Docker Tools to 'add container support' and it added a `docker-compose` project.

When i build it, i get the container built using my re-compiled .net core app and my dockerfile.

Here is the `docker-compose.dcproj`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.0</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>a7cb971b-57ac-4704-851d-a322cf4f9e3f</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.ci.build.yml" />
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here are the files:
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  coresandbox:
    image: coresandbox
    build:
      context: ./CoreSandbox
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

`docker-compose.override.yml`

```
version: '3'
```

`docker-compose.ci.build.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./CoreSandbox.sln && dotnet publish ./CoreSandbox.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

Now i have configured VSTS with the following tasks:
1. Get sources
2. Build Services - Docker Compose
The task looks fairly basic, i left all defaults in place
[image: VSTS task screenshot]

Then i get this log from the build

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/alex/testagent/_work/2/s/docker-compose.yml -f /home/alex/testagent/_work/2/s/docker-compose.ci.build.yml -f /home/alex/testagent/.docker-compose.1505284937228.yml -p newsroomly/CoreSandbox build
Building coresandbox
Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
 ---> a2f5b3f42c0c
Step 2/10 : ARG source
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7a707828214b
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ff4262616387
Step 4/10 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
Service 'coresandbox' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder666656323/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
Building coresandbox
Service 'coresandbox' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder666656323/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose failed with return code: 1
```

Clearly the issue is that the dotnet build task is not run BEFORE compose tries to build the container.

I have also tried `dotnet build my.sln` but as per this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6178 this is not supported, i get `error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Docker.Sdk' specified could not be found.`

It seems that the `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` implies you do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml up` and then you do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build`

However, when i did that, i got the same error about a missing SDK

`/src/docker-compose.dcproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Docker.Sdk' specified could not be found.`

So back to my question - how can i build my dcproj on VSTS

Comment: How about not using the `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` at all, does that help?

Comment: Do you user a hosted agent or private agent? And do you run the build on a Mac or Linux build agent?

Comment: Linux, private. I have found a workaround will post it here later.

Comment: What workaround for this issue? You need to specify docker-compose.ci.build.yml file first (Docker Compose file), then specify docker-compose.yml in additional docker compose file, try it and check the result.

Comment: @starain-MSFT em i did specify it, that just kept failing.
Also, the ci yaml implies that we want to build inside another container (who knows why). So the workaround in a nutshell is - build yourself, using ./obj/Docker as -o path and then the image creation inside the compose can find the files and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution - [VSTS CI/CD with docker and .NET Core 2.0 - Copy failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625045/vsts-ci-cd-with-docker-and-net-core-2-0-copy-failed?rq=1)

I encounter exactly same issue when using .Net framework app.  I used another solution, in the VS solution build step, I had to build with `Release` configuration, otherwise the publish folder won't show up.

One thing you can do is to change this line in your dockerfile, I think this helped me.
Command:

```
/bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./CoreSandbox.sln && dotnet publish ./CoreSandbox.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

to
command:

```
/bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./CoreSandbox.sln && dotnet publish ./CoreSandbox.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker"
```

I spin up my private build agent, and it saves me alot of time instead of downloading the docker images on hosted agent in VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for `/src/docker-compose.dcproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Docker.Sdk' specified could not be found.` is to use the `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0` image instead of `microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0`.

The 2.0 image is missing the Microsoft.Docker.Sdk. This will be fixed in 2.1 starting with preview 2.

Comment: There was this workaround with deploying some files to the CI which actually worked. However i have since moved away from using `dcproj`, it adds 0 value and lots of overhead