# VSTS CI/CD with docker and .NET Core 2.0 - Copy failed

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, .net-core-2.0

While following a couple .NET Core 2.0 Visual Studio Team Services Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery examples I bumped into a copy error in VSTS.

Adding docker support via VS17 works great locally with a dockerfile like this.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

With an MVC app and a WebAPI app it worked well with docker-compose locally.

When adding a VSTS CI build process and running it I kept hitting errors with the copy.

> Building myapp Service 'myapp' failed to
>   build: **COPY failed: GetFileAttributesEx**
>   \?\C:\Windows\TEMP\docker-builder91\obj\Docker\publish: The
>   system cannot find the path specified. C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\docker-compose.exe failed with return code: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround that I've found is [from this blog.](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2017/10/23/continuous-deployment-for-docker-with-vsts-and-azure-container-registry/)

Note that they hit an error on a linux docker machine

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder613328056/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
>   /usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

Solution:

Make a Dockerfile.ci like this

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SiliconValve.Vsts.DockerDemo.dll"]
```

It also requires modifying the .dockerignore file.

```
bin/
obj/
!*.dll
!obj/Docker/publish/*
!obj/Docker/empty/
```

This allows me to continue the CI process, however I assume there's an easier fix to the problem.

Comment: It would be much better IMHO for the build to happen in VSTS and copy the files from there to the Docker image. Can't find how to do that though...

Comment: why we need another file for the CI. what is the difference ?

Comment: Why? Why are we going to do this :D Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build the service from within VSTS and copy them to the Docker image. I used .Net Core VSTS tasks to build and publish to "obj/Docker/Publish" folder and used "Docker-compose" tasks to build and publish docker container to private container repository.