# ASP.NET 4.7.2 - Docker - COPY Failed: CreateFile + The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I have created a brand new ASP.NET 4.7.2 MVC Web Application using Visual Studio 2019. When initializing the solution in Visual Studio 2019, I selected the `Docker support` checkbox. This added a file named `Dockerfile` to my project that looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetput/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

I attempt to build the Docker image using the `build` command from a Docker task in Azure DevOps. When I do this, I get the following:

```
Step 1/13 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
  ---> [id1]
Step 2/13 : ARG source
  ---> Running in [id2]
Removing immediate container [id2]
  ---> [id3]
Step 3/13 : WORKDIR / inetpub/wwwroot
  ---> Running in [id4]
Removing immediate container [id4]
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\docker-build-[id5]\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the path specified.
  ---> [id6]
STEP 4/13 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

What is wrong? Why did the copy fail? Clearly it's because it "cannot find the file". But, I'm not sure where it should be. I did not change the Dockerfile. I simply tried to build a Docker image from a "Hello World" ASP.NET 4.7.2 web app in Azure DevOps. I'm trying to learn how to use Docker with Azure DevOps.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

First, we need to know what does this script line mean. What it expressed is:

Hi Docker, here has a request. Please `COPY` the files you find from the path `$source` into the current directory `.` of the image. If there's nothing in `$source` or it does not exists, just go the default path `obj/Docker/publish` and use it.

In one word, this script is is trying to copy your compiled .NET application bits from obj/Docker/publish

For the script format, you can refer to this [guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

---

Represent the above compilation process in one sentence, it is trying to *copy the compiled ASP.NET application from obj/Docker/publish*.

So, in Azure Devops, you need to add one build task to **build the solution** before you build the image. Then use Copy file task to copy the build files into the docker image. Otherwise, the `${source:-obj/Docker/publish}` folder won't display.

Since your project is a ASP.NET project, you can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?view=azure-devops) and this [blog](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/#exercise-2-examine-the--cicd-pipelines-configured-by-azure-devops-project) to achieve your project built.

---

Also, you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625045/vsts-ci-cd-with-docker-and-net-core-2-0-copy-failed).

The solutions provided in both 2 answers are correct, just the direction are not same. The first solution is to modify the `dockerfile` to make it suitable in Azure devops without any solution build. And in the second answer, it is using tasks I mentioned above in Azure Devops, to achieve the project can be executed with `docker build` by using the default `dockerfile`.